# Keeping password length uniform internally and keeping salt secret?

Tags: security, cryptography, passwords, salt, sha

When storing passwords, it's been said that Salt doesn't need to be secret and it's only purpose is to keep all Hash unique. It's also said that limiting password length is not a good practice but consider this example:

Before hashing, we make sure the plain text version is always 128 characters internally by trimming user input to max 100 then appending additional characters as our salt.

So if user inputs 20 characters, we append 108 random characters as salt. If user inputs 100, we append 28, and so on. The point is, the length of the plain text version should be 128 characters. In code it might look like this:

```
$salt   = generate_salt($pass); // length varies as explained above
$hash   = hash('sha512', $pass.$salt);
```

This way our "plain text" before hash will always be 128 characters.

We store $hash on Server A and store $salt on Server B.

Now let's assume the attacker gains access to hash DB (Server A) and manages to reverse the hashes. Looks good for him but the plain text version (or the reversed hashes) that he sees still looks like hashes since it's 128 characters. Since he doesn't know the salt he will never know the original password.

As an added challenge, due to the fact that SHA512 produces 128 characters he'll also never be sure if he already arrived at the plain text version since (like already mentioned) the plain text version looks like hashes. On plain sight he might think it's an iterated version, if so he'll probably continue to iterate, possibly indefinitely.

Is there any problem with this approach since in the event of hash reversal, keeping the salt secret gives extra security, and, keeping plain text length uniform arguably adds layer of obfuscation?

Note: This of course assumes your app has multiple failed login detection/prevention.

Comment: The point of a hash is that you can't reverse it.

Comment: @zimdanen Agree, but it's "reversible" through rainbow/dictionary attacks

Comment: Which is why you want a salt, but, as you and the answers have mentioned, the salt doesn't need to be kept secret.  The hash itself will keep the data secret; the salt just adds to the complexity of calculating rainbow tables.

Comment: @zimdanen You are right but I think you will agree that if the salt was hidden, you will further prolong the "agony" of the hacker. Otherwise, if he knew the salt, his ordeal is now one step ahead.

Comment: It's all a game of making it more and more difficult for an attacker.  However, I think there are probably other issues in the system that would warrant more attention.  For instance, probably better to focus on keeping the attacker off the system. ;)

Answer (score 3):

**First of all, unless you really know what your doing, don't invent your own crypto system.**

Use an existing one (like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2), [bcrypt](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/) or scrypt), which have advantages over simple salted hashes, since they use more CPU time (all three) and/or memory (the latter two), which makes parallelization expensive.

The salt in a hash protects only against rainbow tables, not against brute-force attacks!.

If the attacker manages to *reverse the hashes*, he will gain knowledge of `$pass.$salt` (an, therefore, the password).

The purpose of a salt is to avoid an inexpensive creation of rainbow tables, that is, instead of just calculating the hashes of every probable password and comparing them to your database, an attacker has to do this for every different salt.

Keeping the salt secret has the theoretical advantage of making the attack even more expensive, since the attacker would also have to try every possible salt for every possible password.

In practice, however, he will probably be able to gain access to server B once he has access to server A.

If something *looks like a hash* is probably not important. Once the server is compromised, the attacker could probably find out what obfuscation techniques are used.

On a side note: `SHA-512` produces 512 bits of output, which are 64 ASCII characters.

Comment: I am not inventing anything, SHA512 is what this example uses. I am just adding higher level implementation on top of it. The underlying crypto hash is SHA512 in this example which means I can replace it with bcrypt, etc.

Comment: He gains `$pass.$salt` but the system truncates/appends random characters in the original pass, concealing the original pass forever. He also doesn't know what the salt is so it is harder for him to figure where the salt begins.

Comment: This example assumes even if all hope is lost, ie: the whole system was compromised. The attacker will never know the original passwords since the original passwords were truncated/appended and therefore useless if tried in other systems like Facebook/Banking/Email/etc.

Comment: SHA512, at least in PHP produces 128 characters.

Comment: *I am not inventing anything* All your ideas regarding the variable length padding etc. **are** a new crypto system. `bcrypt` is specifically designed for passwords, so you don't have to worry about appending a salt, etc., you just use it. *concealing the original pass forever* Knowing `$pass.$salt` means that all the attacker has left to do is guess the length of the password. That takes about 50 tries, and he's done! *the whole system was compromised* If server A can query the passwords from server B, and server A is compromised, there is not reason to assume that server B wouldn't be.

Comment: *SHA512, at least in PHP produces 128 characters.* Yes, but hexadecimal characters (numbers or letters from `A` to `F`).

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with this approach is that you're implementing your own cryptographic code. This is almost always a bad idea; crypto is hard, and very easy to screw up in subtle ways,  and other people have put a lot of time and effort into implementing cryptographic primitives and services built on top of them so that you don't have to. But let's assume for the sake of argument that you really do need to do this :-).

The second thing is that you're truncating the user's input -- throwing away precious entropy -- for no benefit at all. You're prepared to generate up to 128 characters' worth of salt; why not just always do this and feed them (together with the password) into your hash? What do you gain by truncating? The only answer I see is that supposedly the original passwords "look like hashes since it's 128 characters", but that simply isn't true; your salted passwords still begin with actual password data, which typically looks very much unlike hashes.

The third thing -- which may just be a failure on my part to read your mind correctly -- is that it's not clear where these salts of yours are coming from. You describe them as "random" and say attackers won't know them; but then how does your authentication system get them? It seems like they're derived from the password, but in that case salting-plus-hashing is just a marginally more complicated hash function and you haven't really gained anything.

The general principle you've apparently rejected (or perhaps not encountered) is this: *Always design cryptographic systems with the assumption that the attackers know everything they could possibly know, including all your source code*. This is a good principle and you should not reject it. Relying on a small "extra layer of obfuscation" will not serve you well; in the worst case it will make bugs more likely (by complicating the system) and induce a sense of false security.

Comment: First, I'm not implementing my own cryptographic code, the example uses SHA512.

Comment: Second, the purpose was truncating then appending random data (which adds custom entropy), therefore modifying the actual password. Since the original user password was truncated/appended, it will not work with Facebook in case user uses the same password for it. Third, salts are generated and saved in Server B. To authenticate, the app will truncate input, get the salt from server B and compare the hash.

Comment: I agree with the general principle but this example assumes only hash tables were compromised. If indeed the whole system was compromised then reversing hash tables are of no use since attacker basically got all the info he needs. This example assumes that in the event hash tables were reversed, the original user password will never be revealed because the system truncated/appended it. The only chance the attacker can completely recover the original password is if he's able to steal all the system including, server A, server B, and the application codes.

Comment: IMB, you are implementing your own crypto code even if you use SHA512 as a primitive. It's not only the lowest-level primitives that are important, subtle, and very easy to get wrong. Second, appending without truncation gets all the benefits you mention from truncating without the cost. Third, if B is compromised then all salts are known, and anyway if either A or B is compromised then in practice the other probably is too. Fourth, the original password isn't needed because the system only uses the post-truncation bit of it.

Comment: What is true is that if you truncate passwords for this system and truly throw away what you chopped off, then data recovered from the system will be less useful for compromising other systems. In practice I doubt the utility of this, not least because a user whose passwords are actually changed by truncating at 100 characters very likely isn't using the same password for your system as for Facebook anyway.

Answer (score 0):

*Salt doesn't need to be secret and it's only purpose is to keep all Hash unique*

It also makes it 'slower' to brute-force a table of hashes, since you need a try per row for every hash + salt combination instead of just trying out one hash for the whole table (' select * from passwords where hash = 'xxx' ')

*keeping the salt secret gives extra security, and, keeping plain text length uniform arguably adds layer of obfuscation?*

The fact that your 'reversed hashes' look like hashes does not add real extra security (it's really just security by obscurity). Your webserver will need to connect to server A **and** server B (for authenticating a user / password combination) so when that server is compromised all hope is lost.

An article that may interest you is [this blog post by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html). (edit: posted wrong codinghorror link)

Comment: I agree that the whole point is to slow hash reversals and I believe adding "security by obscurity" adds an extra layer of slowness on top of the original cryptographic hash. The point here is to make the attacker's head ache during his whole ordeal.

Comment: All hope is not easily lost since there are several walls the attacker have to go to: 1. Compromise Server A. 2. Compromise Server B. 3. Compromise App code. 4. Reverse the hashes.  5. Figure out the relation between Salt and Hash. 6. If he finds out the App code truncates/appends a bunch of random characters, he will eventually realize he will never ever know the original user password. Now I'm not sure about others but this process is totally slow.